# Duplicate IDs rendered in ASP.NET AJAX TabPanel

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabpanel, tabcontainer

I have two user controls (.ascx) in which I have an ASP.NET AJAX TabContainer control, each with two or three tabs (TabPanels). I use these controls in around 10 websites. All have worked fine, except the latest three websites. In those three, the TabPanel controls are rendered with duplicate id attributes, so the tab's div on the browser looks similar to this:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mycontrol1_mycontrolTabs_ctl00" 
  id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mycontrol1_mycontrolTabs_ctl00" 
  class="ajax__tab_panel">
```

None of the other markup in the TabContainer has duplicate ids, only the TabPanels. The earlier websites render this exact same user control with a single id (it's exactly the same because the sites share the same folder with the controls via a virtual directory). I've tried omitting the ID on the TabPanel but it still renders duplicate ids.

This only seems to raise an error in IE7 and IE8, but unfortunately support for these is required for one of the offending sites.

I have compared the 'good' and 'bad' websites thoroughly but have not found anything that should trigger this behavior in the tab control. The websites vary a little in content but are really quite similar. Any ideas on what might be triggering this are welcome!

Comment: This is somehow related to the AjaxControlToolkit version. The old sites were using the 40412 build, the newer ones the 51116 build. Replacing the newer one with the older one caused the error to go away. I also tried the latest build (60623) but still got duplicate IDs. However at some point I may need to upgrade, so I'm still looking for an explanation of the cause.